# Do the scriptures mention any prayer as a sure shot way to fulfill one's desires in a specified period of time?

Tags: prayer

If yes, which prayer/ritual is this and how is it performed?

Comment: What type of desires? If the desires are against niyathi, then no prayer will be there...